# free soundless clips

Tags: sound-design, practice

Hi im a recent graduate with a certificate in Audio Engineering. The school i attended was mainly studio music recording. However it touched on sound design and opened a whole new world to me. Does anyone know where to get free clips without sound just for sound design practice? Doesnt matter if its film, animation, logos, whatever. Any info would be great, thanks.

Comment: I like to look around on hd-trailers.net for movie teasers which are less than 2mins to practice on, unfortunately I've begun projects but never completed them lol.

Comment: Forgot to mention, after I download a teaser I use Mediacoder to remove the audio and convert to MJPEG and a lower resolution so it can run quicker on Pro Tools.

Answer (score 5):

[Archive.org](http://www.archive.org)'s video archives are a goldmine!  There are lots of fun videos there - old war clips, home movies, tv shows... sky's the limit!  If you want something exceptionally fun, I have 16mm of the moon landing - a little silent reel that could use some sound.

Video game and movie trailers are also a great source for practice.

Comment: I was unaware of this website. thanks alot!

Answer (score 4):

[search vimeo for creative commons.](http://vimeo.com/search/videos/search%3acreative%20commons/st/2de55c72)

Vimeo hosts files at pretty high quality, and the clips that are posted and tagged as creative commons licensed are explicitly available for use in the context you're seeking. Many film makers also make the original files available for download directly from Vimeo.

Its also likely to be new and interesting stuff that will inspire and challenge you, and when you show it to others they'll be seeing high quality stuff they haven't ever seen before.  In some cases you can even make a connection with the original animator or film maker and start a network in that direction right away.

Answer (score 0):

For the practice you can use any material. But don't use trailers or similar production. I think that modern trailer sound re-design enthusiasm is a very bad idea.

My point, it would be better if you select some movie with specified scene (uncut) which contain certain sense or idea. Like jungle sequence in Avatar, fight episode in Matrix or the scene with the feeding of the small dragons in How to Train Your Dragon (it's a really great moment I think!).

And here you can create not only your own sound, but also you can show how you feel the scene, your vision of design, editing and so forth.

When creating sound for trailer you can go wrong way. Since there is another destination in term of sound design.

Answer (score 0):

I use a program called cinematize which allows you to remove all the sound from a clip that you load in. I find it really useful when I am teaching and need to assign the students a sound design project. Also, there are loads of interesting short films available on the net that I found that test various levels of creativity and theory.

Here is one site that explains cinematize:

http://www.miraizon.com/products/products.html

Answer (score -1):

Try http://www.freesound.org/

Comment: Freesound is good for free sounds, but not for free video clips.